# Why don't use len instead of str.length() here in StringUtils,Spring-Core?

Tags: java, spring, string

```
    public static String trimAllWhitespace(String str) {
    if (!hasLength(str)) {
        return str;
    }

    int len = str.length();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Why don't use len instead of str.length() here in StringUtils,Spring-Core?

Comment: Look at the change history. For example, at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e7f89f87c14bb65a83518508a791dc68e681ddd4/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.java, you'll see that the `StringBuilder` was initialized with the `str` value, and whitespace was being deleted. This change was introduced in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/4d328d6188f4103b2162bba118c964fe7f52caf9#diff-2d1af2f602408affc011becfdbdb6be5, and I suspect it to be an oversight in the use of `len`.

Answer (score 1):

len is the better choice as it avoids the overhead of any additional method calls to String.length()

Comment: Doesn't the compiler optimize that anyway?